# Render the screen when clicked on stack navigator tab

Tags: ios, react-native, tabnavigator

I crated a tab view using `TabNavigator`. Here is the [library](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) I used. Total I have 3 tabs. So Initial tab is loading & rendering fine without hassle. But the problem is coming with 3rd Tab. I checked with `console.log()` in every method in that 3rd tab component. Every method is executing but not showing results ( Showing blank screen) until I interact with it. When I start interacting with it, then only data is re-rendering(I think so).

How can I solve this problem? Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by configuring tab navigator with prop `lazy` true. Below is the code I modified. It's working now.

```
const TabView = TabNavigator({
                         feed: { screen: Feed },
                         info: { screen: Info },
                         members: {screen: Members}
                         }, {
                         tabBarPosition: "top",
                         tabBarOptions: {
                            activeTintColor: "#4A90E2",
                            inactiveTintColor: "#4A4A4A",
                            style: {
                                backgroundColor: 'white',
                                height:56,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                 shadowColor: '#000000',
                                 shadowOpacity: 0.1,
                                 shadowRadius: 0,
                                 shadowOffset: {
                                    height: 2,
                                    width: 1
                                 }

                            },
                            tabStyle: {
                                height: 40,
                            },
                            labelStyle: {
                                fontSize:12,
                                fontFamily:'HelveticaNeue-Medium'
                            }

                         },
                         lazy:true
                         });
```

Comment: lazy: true means that the tabs in the background are not rendered until clicked upon. With lazy: false, switching tabs will be instant. If on the last tab what you have is a ListView, or a FlatList/SectionList, you can try setting  removeClippedSubviews={false} on the ListView, this may help with component not showing correctly.